# Adelantar/desplazar/mover/trasladar la cita

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Si uno tiene una cita pendiente al final de este mes y quisiera reprogramarla al principio del mismo mes (no sé si está bien dicho...), ¿se puede   preguntar al/a la organizador/ra de citas de la siguiente forma? ¡Gracias!

"¿Podría usted adelantar/desplazar/mover/trasladar la cita al principio de este mes?"

Comment: Por favor, si deseas usar lenguaje inclusivo hazlo solo cuando sea realmente ofensivo o discriminatorio no usarlo. En tu pregunta, el fragmento _"al/a la organizador/ra"_ solo dificulta la comunicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende muchas veces de la persona y el vocabulario que estas utilicen de forma habitual, la verdad es que no existe un modo único, lo que normalmente escucho por mi zona y donde no oigo términos como "*trasladar*" o "*mover*", es lo siguiente;

- ¿ Podría **cambiarme** la fecha a principio de este mes?
- ¿ Podría **pasarme** la fecha a principio de este mes?
- ¿ Podría **adelantarme** la fecha a principio de este mes?

**P.D.** Dentro de estas tres expresiones, la más utilizada es la primera, con el verbo "*cambiar*", "**cambiarme la fecha**" a principio de este mes?

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por las explicaciones de Ustedes! Tengo una pregunta más: ¿Significan lo mimo "a principio" y "a principios"? Muchas gracias otra vez y saludos 

Comment: ¡Gracias a ti! Tanto la expresión "a principio" como "a principios" son validas. Igualmente con el mismo significado puede utilizarse "a comienzo" y "a comienzos". Ejemplo: ¿ Podría adelantarme la fecha a comienzos de este mes?

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por su respuesta, Diego!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que comunmente se utiliza es adelantar, aunque como lo que se desea cambiar es la fecha y no la cita, lo correcto sería:

¿Podría usted anticipar la fecha de la cita a principio de este mes?

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría algo como

> ¿Es posible reprogramar la cita para el principio de este mes?

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a Usted también, Cerulean! Quisiera preguntar si se puede sustituir "para el principio" por "a principio(s)" en "¿Es posible reprogramar la cita para el principio de este mes?". Si la respuesta es un "no", ¿no sé si me podrían explicar el porqué? Muchísimas gracias otra vez 