# "Para el principio" va. "a principio(s)"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Quisiera preguntar si se puede sustituir "para el principio" por "a principio(s)" en "[¿Es posible reprogramar la cita para el principio de este mes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/41894/adelantar-desplazar-mover-trasladar-la-cita/41897?noredirect=1#comment74160_41897)". Si la respuesta es un "no", ¿no sé si me podrían explicar el porqué? ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La respuesta es si. Estás en lo cierto. Se puede sustituir "*para el principio*" por " "*a principio(s)*". Es correcto.

- "¿Es posible reprogramar la cita **para principio** de este mes?"
- "¿Es posible reprogramar la cita **a principio** de este mes?"

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda, Diego!

Comment: ¡ Gracias a ti ! ¡Saludos!

Comment: Para mi esas frases tienen diferente significado. La primera indica **para cuándo** es la cita y la segunda **cuándo** es posible reprogramarla.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, las dos frases son correctas pero significan cosas diferentes.

La clave son las preposiciones. «a» o «para»

1- Su cita es dentro de dos meses pero puede reprogramarla **a principios** de la próxima semana.
2- Su cita es dentro de dos meses pero puede reprogramarla **para principios (para el principio)** de la próxima semana.

En el primer caso, es posible reprogramar la cita **durante** los primeros días de la próxima semana, y puede reprogramarse para cualquier otra fecha.
En el segundo caso es posible cambiar la cita que es dentro de dos meses **para** los primeros días de la próxima semana.